# How to create a dictionary from Excel with list as values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

INPUT- This is an excel sheet

| DatasetName | Fields |
| --- | --- |
| Table_1 | Column1 |
| Table_1 | Column2 |
| Table_1 | Column3 |
| Table_1 | Column4 |
| Table_2 | Column1 |
| Table_2 | Column2 |
| Table_2 | Column3 |
| Table_2 | Column4 |
| Table_3 | Column1 |
| Table_3 | Column2 |
| Table_3 | Column3 |
| Table_3 | Column4 |

OUTPUT-

```
{'Table_1' : ['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'] ,
 'Table_2' : ['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'] ,
 'Table_3' : ['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4'] }
```

Comment: Could you add what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Leverage on the powerful Pandas features on data grouping and aggregation:

You can do it easily with just one line with [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) + [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html), as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# read the Excel into dataframe `df`
df = pd.read_excel('my_excel.xlsx')

# generate dict 
dict_out = df.groupby('DatasetName')['Fields'].agg(list).to_dict()
```

**Result:**

```
print(dict_out)

{'Table_1 ': ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'],
 'Table_2': ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4'],
 'Table_3': ['Column1', 'Column2', 'Column3', 'Column4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
# Get the unique dataset names 
names = df['DatasetName'].unique()

result = {}
# Loop over the names, get the corresponding values, store them as a list
for name in names:
    x = df.loc[df['DatasetName'] == name]
    vals = x['Fields'].tolist()
    result[name] = vals

print(result)
```